# Why am I getting a invalid number from a varchar field on which I'm running regexp_replace?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (FIRST, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'g')
  FROM example
 WHERE LAST LIKE '%Belanger%'
```

'first' is a varchar2 field. I'm just trying to remove the non-alphanumeric characters from the 'first field.

Comment: You're passing invalid args to `regexp_replace`. See the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302

Comment: Reading these docs, I'm still having trouble to figure out WHICH args are invalid. Mind sharing?

Comment: It should be something like `regexp_replace(first, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', null, 1, 0)`. The 1 indicates the start position, and the 0 says to replace all matches. 'g' is not valid.

Comment: The fourth parameter is _start\_parmeter_ @KinsDotNet. You've got a `g` in there,  not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where last LIKE 'Belanger'` only returns rows where `last` equals `"Belanger"`. Add appropriate wildcards

```
WHERE last LIKE '%Belanger%'  -- contains 'Belanger'
```

or

```
WHERE last LIKE 'Belanger%'  -- starts with 'Belanger'
```

or

```
 WHERE last LIKE '%Belanger'  -- ends with 'Belanger'
```

or (without LIKE)

```
 WHERE last = 'Belanger'  -- equals 'Belanger'
```

It also looks like the syntax for `regexp_replace` is wrong. syntax:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( string, pattern [, replacement_string [, start_position
                [, nth_appearance [, match_parameter ] ] ] ] )
```

The last parameter is `match_parameter` which has to be preceeded by `start_position` and `nth_appearance`. Valid match parameters are (according to [TechNet REGEXP_REPLACE Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php)):

> 'c'     Perform case-sensitive matching.
>   'i'       Perform case-insensitive matching.
>   'n'     Allows the period character (.) to match the newline character.
>            By default, the period is a wildcard.
>   'm'      expression is assumed to have multiple lines, where ^ is the start of a line and $ is the end of
>            a line, regardless of the position of those characters in expression. By default, expression is assumed to be a single line.
>   'x'     Whitespace characters are ignored. By default, whitespace characters are matched like any
>            other character.

However, this should work without this `'g'` parameter (whatever it was meant to do):

```
regexp_replace(first, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '')
```

Comment: Fixed in the question. Not the answer. Still getting ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `'g'` on this place. Following query is enough. Check it in documentation provided by @kfinity

```
SELECT regexp_replace(first, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '')
          FROM example
          where last LIKE '%Belanger%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace anything that is not in ranges `a-z` or `0-9` with null, starting at position 1, all occurrences, case-insensitive):

```
regexp_replace(first, '[^a-z0-9]+', '', 1, 0, 'i')
```

or this (replace anything in the POSIX `[:alnum:]` (alphanumeric) [character class](https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/regex/character-classes/)):

```
regexp_replace(first, '[^[:alnum:]]')
```